# If I VPN into a network on a VirtualBox guest, is the network traffic of the host also funneled to the VPN network?

Tags: vpn, virtualbox, cisco-vpn

I have a machine at my house that runs linux.  I use VirtualBox to run an XP host so I can VPN to my workplace.

Im curious if the network traffic from the linux host also goes to the VPN network that I have connected on the guest OS?

My workplace as strict rules on steaming audio/video, etc... over the corporate network and while at home I dont want to accidentally violate these rules.  Would I be able to stream from the host machine and work from the guest vm and be ok?

Thanks!
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the VPN would remain local to your VirtualBox guest. You should be just fine continuing to stream music/video from the host OS.